# Get the value after the radix point in a float

Tags: objective-c, c, floating-point

What would be the best way to get the value after the radix point in a float? For example, 0.4000, 13.67324 get 4000 and 67324 respectively.

Comment: what is your input? text or a float number?

Comment: If it is a `float`, how do you know it's 0.4000 and not 0.4?

Comment: @Iulian Şerbănoiu I mentioned radix point in a float. So the input is a float number.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't. It can be 0.4000 and 0.4. If it is mandatory to know the exact length of the digits after the radix point in order to strip them, then let us assume the digits are always known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int s = (number > 0 ? 1 : -1);

number *=s;

float t = s*(number - floorf(number));
int n = (int) (t * pow(10,k));
```

where `number` is your float number and `k` is the number of digit you want.

Comment: (-1) this doesn't work for negative numbers `-0.3` for example

Comment: and also, what is the logic in multiplying by the number of digits?

Comment: @Saphrosit Have you tried your solution? I just did and it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: I forgot the parentheses in the final computation. Try now, it should works.